# Using List instead of IEnumerable in Model cannot disable or enable the Textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Hope you all are well. I'm working on a software and need to disable or enable the textbox using the Bit value of Table but can't works for me.
When I try to add List instead of IEnumerable in Model it works but I have to use List model instead of IEnumerable in my View.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
@model List<EapprovalWAKWebApplication.Models.ElementEntriesDetail>
     @*@foreach (var item in Model)*@
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
 @if (modelItem => modelItem[i].OverrideValue == false)
                    {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].OverwriteValue, new { @id = "overvalue", disabled = "disabled" })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].OverwriteValue, new { @id = "overvalue" })
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how you'd reference something in a loop:

```
if (modelItem => modelItem[i].OverrideValue == false)
```

If you're iterating over `Model`, then you'd apply your indexer (`i`) to `Model`:

```
if (Model[i].OverrideValue == false)
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
if (!Model[i].OverrideValue)
```

Comment: Hi david can you help me in some piece of Code actually I stuck again badly and really need your help to complete the task. Waiting for your reply.